# PHP Parse JPEG File and retrieve image dimensons

Tags: php, jpeg

I'm trying to parse a JPEG file in PHP and retrieve the image dimensons and then store them as an external variable to be used in a subsequent function that takes some action based on the image dimensions.

```
<html>
<head>
 <title>PHP Test</title>
  </head>
   <body>
    <?php
    $filename= '437-1.jpg.JPG';
    $size = array getimagesize (string $filename [,array &$imageinfo]);
    echo $size;
    ?> 
 </body>
</html
```

Neither of these seem to be working - could anybody tell me where I'm going wrong?

Thanks,

A

Comment: 1. Is the file *actually* called `437-1.jpg.JPG`? 2. You can't just copy paste what it says in the manual - that's not how PHP works. `$size = getimagesize($filename);`.

Comment: Everything is wrong.. Look at the syntax. You used the DOCS syntax inside php code.

Comment: With GD you can use 'getImageSize' : http://tw1.php.net/getimagesize

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$filename = '437-1.jpg.JPG';
$size = getimagesize($filename);
print_r($size);
if ($size) {
   echo 'Width:' . $size[0] . 'px <br>';
   echo 'Height:' . $size[1] . 'px <br>';
}
```

But first spend some time and learn PHP syntax.

Comment: Thanks - where does this print to? I don't see anything in the Komodo Browser Preview. Just a blank page?

Comment: to standard output, wrap this php code with <?php ?> tags.. if it still doesn't work maybe you don't have installed/enabled GD library. Check the phpinfo() output. Also check the error logging level, if you have blank page looks like you don't have enabled error log. Do it by putting "error_reporting(E_ALL);" in first line of your php code